# bibliography goes to next next page but i want it to continue to my current page

Tags: bibtex

here is my minimum code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% author.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% sample root file for your "contribution" to a proceedings volume
%
% Use this file as a template for your own input.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Springer %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{svproc}

\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlFont{\rmfamily}
%\usepackage{ecrc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter              % start of a contribution
%
    % typeset the title of the contribution
\begin{abstract}
fgggggggjmnfghndgcnnnnnbhhvbvbvbvbnnnvvncnv

\end{abstract}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
\label{sec1}
ghjfgjhmkfuyhjmjgmjk
fvjmnvjhnjmjhm,


\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? If you are asking why there is a new page before the section "INTRODUCTION": that can be a consequence of the class you are using (`svproc` in this case).

Comment: Svproc is not a standard class so perhaps mention where you got it from. If you were instructed to use it, then don't change the behaviour! I'm assuming this is some kind of conference proceedings or similar. The people at the receiving end get quite annoyed when they receive contributions where the author have been changing the template.

Answer (score 1):

Normally there is clearpage before bibliography, trick it to not insert page break:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% author.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% sample root file for your "contribution" to a proceedings volume
%
% Use this file as a template for your own input.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Springer %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{svproc}

\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlFont{\rmfamily}
%\usepackage{ecrc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter              % start of a contribution
%
    % typeset the title of the contribution
\begin{abstract}
fgggggggjmnfghndgcnnnnnbhhvbvbvbvbnnnvvncnv

\end{abstract}
\section{INTRODUCTION}
\label{sec1}
ghjfgjhmkfuyhjmjgmjk
fvjmnvjhnjmjhm,
\cite{knuth}

\begingroup

\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{bib}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]